# Force Stripe WooCommerce Addon into testmode depending on hostname

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm looking for a way to force the Stripe Woocommerce addon into test mode if the site is set up locally or on a staging site. I've yet to find any resources that can point me in the right direction.

I've found the code in class-wc-gateway-strip.php that gets setting values:

```
// Get setting values.
    $this->title                  = $this->get_option( 'title' );
    $this->description            = $this->get_option( 'description' );
    $this->enabled                = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
    $this->testmode               = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'testmode' );
    $this->capture                = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'capture', 'yes' );
    $this->stripe_checkout        = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'stripe_checkout' );
    $this->stripe_checkout_locale = $this->get_option( 'stripe_checkout_locale' );
    $this->stripe_checkout_image  = $this->get_option( 'stripe_checkout_image', '' );
    $this->saved_cards            = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'saved_cards' );
    $this->secret_key             = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_secret_key' ) : $this->get_option( 'secret_key' );
    $this->publishable_key        = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_publishable_key' ) : $this->get_option( 'publishable_key' );
    $this->bitcoin                = 'USD' === strtoupper( get_woocommerce_currency() ) && 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'stripe_bitcoin' );
    $this->logging                = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'logging' );
```

And I've tried doing a check on the domain and tried `update_option('testmode','yes');` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas or resources that can help me move forward?

Comment: If you can find the actual option name you may be able to filter it via [`pre_option_$option_name`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/option.php#L52)

Comment: Nevermind, I *think* all the stripe settings are saved as an array under `woocommerce_stripe_settings`. So you'd need to `get_option("woocommerce_stripe_settings")`, manipulate the resulting array, and then `update_option()` with the new data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but based on my comments, I think you can adjust the options.

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_40555974_stripe_testing' );
function so_40555974_stripe_testing(){

    $localIPs = array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '::1'
    );

    // or use your own conditional logic for determining local/testing server
    if( in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localIPs ) ){
        $settings = get_option("woocommerce_stripe_settings");
        $settings["testmode"] = "yes";
        update_option("woocommerce_stripe_settings", $settings );
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally forgot I posted this, but this is what I ended up doing too. Thanks!

Comment: If this ended up being the answer for you, could you accept it?